# Create relations between identical tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm sorry for the title, I couldn't come up with anything more specific.

Here's an example of my problem.

I have 2 tables.

*london(name varchar,email varchar)*

*madrid(name varchar,email varchar)*

What I'm doing is getting data from both tables(please mind that in MY case we are talking about over hundred of them) and present data for each as well as "global" data for all of them combined. For now I'm going through *table_schema* and loop through all the tables. What I would like to do is create a third table

*global(name varchar,email varchar)*

which would store every commit in both *london* and *madrid* upon entry. Is there a way of creating "symlinks" and not hard copying every entry? Every entry has an unique ID.

Also, I'm not in position to merge the db into one table.

Comment: The correct way would be to do your global(name, email, cityid) where cityid links to a table city(id, name)

Comment: Why not create ONE table but with a `city` column

Comment: @RiggsFolly Also, I'm not in position to merge the db into one table.

Comment: what a crazy DB structure. I agree with Riggs, this will continue to give you awkward problems like this until you redesign it and normalise it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a VIEW Called global which UNIONS the results of london and madrid?

```
SELECT A.*,'LONDON' as City 
FROM london A 
UNION ALL 
SELECT A.*, 'MADRID' 
FROM  Madrid A
```

I added a city columns so you had a way to know WHICH record came from which table.

`UNION ALL` avoids the running of the distinct in just a `union` which aids performance.

Comment: One hell of a union with 100+ selects, but i guess thats the way to go if table merge really really aint in the cards

Comment: Would a view support all table queries? I'm running a lot of "SELECT * WHERE Date LIKE ".

Comment: @Noino I interperted 100+ as 100 + records not 100+ tables.

Comment: A view will support all table queries;  but I would be concerned about performance.  You could implement a materialized view concept (sadly the exact method doesn't exist in MySQL) with triggers to keep the tables in sync: This [article](http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views) explains the approach. This has the advantage of allowing you to create indexes on the table so your performance hit on queries is reduced.  However, it comes at a cost of each insert/update/delete now has to have overhead to maintain the data in the table via trigger.

Comment: A view will support all ***read*** table queries, updates and deletes which effect more than 1 table wouldn't likely work.